# IConfiguration does not retrieve values from appsettings.json but from Azure Key Vault

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-keyvault, appsettings

Inside the Program.cs file of a .NET Core 3.1 Web API i got the following:

```
    public class Program
{

    private static string _someValue;

    public Program(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _someValue = configuration["SOME_VALUE"]

    }
```

inside the appsettings.json i got:

```
{
 "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
},
 "SOME_VALUE": "value"

}
```

The problem is, i am not able to get the value "SOME_VALUE" from the appsettings.json. But i got this same value inside an Azure Key Vault and for some reason it gets the values from there. Can someone explain why that is the case?

Comment: Unless you have changed the default setup, then KeyVault will be higher priority since you added it after the basic configuration was set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration providers are executed in a specific order
[image]

In your case, the Azure KeyVault will be at the top (or, to be more precise it is between AddUserSecrets and AddEnvironmentVariables)

[See docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configuration-providers)

Order configuration providers in code to suit the priorities for the underlying configuration sources that the app requires or use different variable name

Comment: Is there any way to change this order?

Comment: Yes, `ClearProviders()` then add